# How do I describe the curve $x = \sqrt{1 + y^{2}}$ in polar coordinates?

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

Could someone explain to me how this conversion from cartesian to polar form is done with this type of equation?

> Show that the curve $x = \sqrt{1+y^2}$ can be described in polar coordinates by $$r^2 = \frac 1 {\cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta}.$$

Comment: Use the usual polar conversion formulas (let $x = r \cos \theta$ and $y = r \sin \theta$), and solve for $r^2$, manipulating trig identities as you need to along the way

Comment: $\cos^2{\theta}-\sin^2{\theta}=\cos{2\theta}$. This describes one half of a hyperbola.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that $x \geq 1$, one gets the following result:

\begin{align*}
x = \sqrt{1 + y^{2}} & \Longleftrightarrow x^{2} = 1 + y^{2}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow x^{2} - y^{2} = 1\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow r^{2}(\cos^{2}(\theta) - \sin^{2}(\theta)) = 1\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow r^{2}\cos(2\theta) = 1
\end{align*}

Based on it, I think you meant
\begin{align*}
r^{2} = \frac{1}{\cos^{2}(\theta) \color{red}{-} \sin^{2}(\theta)}
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thank you! This makes so much more sense than the way I was trying to solve this. I have been struggling with this topic for a while now, your answer helped clear some things up for me! - CC

Comment: @calculusconfusion you are welcome! I am glad to help.